# Как в bash скрипте использовать несколько раз egrep

Tags: bash, grep

У меня есть go script для мониторинга rtsp протокола и я никак не пойму как сделать так, чтобы после запуска скрипта делать поиск выражений в выводе.
Сделал примерный bash скрипт -

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ "$(sh run.sh | egrep '(RTSP/1.0) [0-9][0-9][0-9]' | tail -1)" ]; then
    echo OK
#elif  egrep 'qwert'; then
#   echo bad
else
    echo ERROR
fi
```

Мне нужно если нашел допустим rtsp/1.0 200, то пиши ОК, а если допустим rtsp/1.0 400, то BAD  и т.д. Но запускать скрипт только один раз.

Comment: Сохранить вывод `sh run.sh` во временный файл и запускать grep по этому файлу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить такую заготовку:

```
#!/bin/bash

./run.sh |
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    if [[ $line =~ "regex_pattern" ]];
    then
         echo "есть совпадение"
    fi
  done
```

Вывод скрипта отправляется на бесконечный `while` цикл, где построчно прогоняется на предмет совпадения с `regex_pattern`.

Comment: Почти, но совсем не то, надо чтобы он только одно слово вывел)

Comment: @AnuarMukatov "Почти, но совсем не то"? )) Добавьте тогда в описание вашего вопроса все условия. Вот, например, вывели слово один раз, а что потом? Завершение скрипта? Или повторить вывод через сутки?

Comment: Прошу прощенья, не подумал. Да, нужно чтобы одно слово было в echo, а не каждую строчку echo и завершение скрипта.

Comment: @AnuarMukatov можно просто добавить `exit 0` строчкой ниже `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

Имхо вот так попроще и наворотов поменьше:

```
while read -r line; do
    [[ "$line" =~ RTSP/1.0 200 ]] && {
        echo DONE
        exit 0 # Это чтобы потом можно было обработать результат выполения скрипта если необходимо
    }
    [[ "$line" =~ RTSP/1.0 400 ]] && {
        echo ERROR
        exit 1 # Это для того-же что и exit 0
    }
done < <(./run.sh)
```